# update the unselectable value (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectable

i'm using selectable jquery, i want to cater the value for selectable once the use select or unselect the item. My problem is, the last value of unselectable won't update.
Full code here http://jsfiddle.net/duQH6/ When I select Mon and Tue, then I unselect the Tue, the value is updated, but then when I click Mon, the value is not updated. Please advice.

Here my jquery code

```
$(function() {
$("#selectday1").bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable();
}); 

$('document').ready(function(){ 
$( "#selectday1" ).selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        var result=[];
        jQuery(".ui-selected", this).each(function() 
        {
        result.push(this.id);
        $("#days").val(result.join(','))
        });
    }
});
$( "#selectday1" ).selectable({
    unselected: function(event, ui) {
        var result=[];
        jQuery(".ui-selected", this).each(function() 
        {
        result.push(this.id);
        $("#days").val(result.join(','))
        });
    }
});
});
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are updating the `days` value within the `each` loop, so when you unselect the last element the loop callback is never executed, that is why it is happening.

The `days` value is supposed to be updated once the `each()` loop is completed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectday1").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            var result = [];
            jQuery(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                result.push(this.id);
            });
            $("#days").val(result.join(','))
        },
        unselected: function (event, ui) {
            var result = [];
            jQuery(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                result.push(this.id);
            });
            $("#days").val(result.join(','))
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LQ2G3/)

But it can be simplified to

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function serialize(event, ui) {
        var result = $(this).find(".ui-selected").map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get();
        $("#days").val(result.join(','))
    }

    $("#selectday1").selectable({
        selected: serialize,
        unselected: serialize
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rMBkM/)

Comment: 1st answer is more easy for me to understand. :) thanks anyway.